# ¿Cómo insertar múltiples imágenes en una celda de una tabla en html?

Tags: html, css

Estoy queriendo insertar muchas imágenes dentro de una celda en HTML. E probado con `object-position` pero no se me estarían acomodando las imágenes.

Busco que cada imagen esté una en cada esquina (superior izquierda y derecha e inferior izquierda y derecha).

Así es como lo estoy intentando:

```
            <tr>
                <td>1111</td>
                <td>1111</td>
                <td>1111</td>
                <td style="padding: 0; margin: 0; padding-bottom: 20px; display: flex">
                    <img style="object-position: left top; width:100px; height: 100px;" src="~/ImgAndroid/Prueba1.jpg"/>
                    <img style="object-position: right top; width:100px; height: 100px;" src="~/ImgAndroid/Prueba2.jpg"/>
                    <img style="object-position: left bottom;width:100px; height: 100px;" src="~/ImgAndroid/Prueba3.jpg"/>
                    <img style="object-position: left bottom;width:100px; height: 100px;" src="~/ImgAndroid/Prueba4.jpg"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Los estilos los puse en las etiquetas pero están en su propio archivo.

**MUY** vulgarmente esto es lo que busco

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en caso de tener más de 4 imágenes, que en la última imagen pueda hacer clic y abrir todas las imágenes (Esto creo que se hace con Js, pero primero quiero ubicar cada foto en su respectivo lugar)

Espero que se haya entendido y pido perdón por la pobre imagen ilustrativa que hice para el ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar [Grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

#### Ejemplo:

El ejemplo muestra las imágenes dentro de un grid de 2 columnas con filas de un mínimo de 100 píxeles y un máximo automático.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  vertical-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 8px;
}
img {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 8px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1111</td>
    <td>1111</td>
    <td>1111</td>
    <td>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img alt="Image 1" />
        <img alt="Image 2" />
        <img alt="Image 3" />
        <img alt="Image 4" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias! Ahora si funciona